# Power BI Card data alignment

Tags: powerbi, dashboard, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I need to create a report like below. (figure 1)
[image: dashboard figures]

I have created measures and added to the report using a Card. It's looks like below. (figure 2)

[image: card data]

There is no alignment options available in Card Visual so I can't align data as I needed.

How could I create a report as shown in Figure 1 in Power BI?

Comment: The standard card visual doesn't support alignment. Try a third party visual from the store, or the standard multicard visual has left aligned text and options for more than one measure

Comment: Friendly reminder that you should accept one of the answers. It is a way people in the future will be able to easily find the correct answers to their questions.

Comment: Hi @Max, What if there is no answer solved my problem or helpful in finding my solution?

Comment: Then don't accept ofcourse! But then you could better answer the answers that didnt work asking for clarification. I'm pretty sure smpa01's answer will do the trick, I also always use that visual for cards instead of the original.

Comment: @Max smpa01 answered on 2021-11-24. I asked the question on 2020-05-02. So I'm not going to check that answer because I don't have this requirement anymore.

Comment: Excuse me dearly Bishan, I was unaware of your asking date. Consider my comments not placed.

Comment: I have created a custom Power BI visual for my requirement. If anyone interested how, follow [Develop your own Power BI visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/develop-power-bi-visuals)

Answer (score 2):

You need this
https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/wa104381651?tab=overview
Advanced card has the alignment properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a rectangle behind, same background color, make your card visual as small as possible, remove title etc and position it on the rectangle, then send the rectangle 'to back', under Format. Messy but works. Grouping the 2 objects helps to keep them in place and resolves the click behaviour bringing the rectangle forward. Might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to align properly is to select your card and go to the format options, and the general section.
You will find x-y coordinates what will allow you to perfectly align your visual.

Comment: You are talking about the visual itself. The X-Y coordinates just change the position of the visual on the canvas. What the OP is asking about is the position of the data *within* the visual. This is a feature I'm looking forward to too